# How to print as PDF using Acrobat 10, when no printer is installed?

Tags: pdf

Preview or Acrobat can both print out individual pages of a PDF file, as a new PDF file containing only those pages, but I think Acrobat 10 probably can print out page 1, 10-12, and 5 -- in any order, while Preview can only print out the "selected page" and must be in ascending page number order.

Preview can do that, but if using Acrobat 10, then going to `File -> Print` will actually trigger a "No printer is installed.  Please install a printer first"...  The thing is, I am really trying to print as a PDF file and there is no printer around... so is there a way to get past that dialog and print the pages as a PDF file?

Comment: Have you tried using export rather then print?

Comment: There isn't an "export" on my Acrobat 10 on the Mac... (Acrobat Reader X (10.1.1))

Comment: It should be in the Print dialog under "Print to PDF" in the left-hand corner of the dialog.

Comment: Don't you need Adobe Distiller for full PDF printing?

Answer (score -1):

When you have a file that you want to print as a PDF, go to "Print.." (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and select "PDF" in the left hand corner:
[image]

Then select "Save as PDF...":
[image]
Then, you'll be presented with a save dialog:
[image]
Using this method, you shouldn't need to have a printer installed.

Comment: did you try it with Acrobat 10?  (as in the question, works ok in Preview but not with Acrobat 10)

Comment: You clearly didn't read the OP =/